# Wordpress reCAPTCHA Problem

Tags: wp-login-form

I have a WordPress site that has a google recaptcha on the login page, the problem is apparently it's outdated and now I can't even get in the background to update it. the google page it links you too is less than helpful.

If anyone could provide some insight that'd be great!

[image]

Comment: if you have FTP access to your site, you can look in the `wp-content/plugins/` folder for it. It's name should be apparent. Rename the folder of the plugin with an underscore prefix (or something like that), & that'll disable it.

Comment: Hi @DavidSword i did look and didnt see any plugins that seemed related to recaptcha [https://i.gyazo.com/44ef6349e8ab37ce947f95677aa5e4a3.png]

Comment: Could this be some setting in your theme? (Then rename the theme folder)

Comment: @kero I'v ruled out the theme, as I used a default theme, 2 of them to be precise. I set them in the database, and the login page still includes that recapcha.

Comment: The text in the OP says “your host added” - maybe contact them?

Answer (score 0):

The host had to disable a line in the php ini file in the root public_html folder. Looks like they enable it by default, but forgot to change then when it got depreciated.